# Android - Proguard stripping away Parcelable Creator

Tags: android, parcelable, android-proguard

I have a library project which has Proguard rules on it. These are stated below

```
  -keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
     public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
  }

  -keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
  }
```

One of my classes named **Actor** implements `Parcelable` whose creator is like

```
public static final Creator<Actor> CREATOR = new Creator<Actor>()
{
    public Actor createFromParcel(Parcel pc)
    {
        return new Actor(pc);
    }

    public Actor[] newArray(int size)
    {
        return new Actor[size];
    }
};
```

Then, AAR is created and I am importing the library project to my project using *compile* in gradle. Then I am trying to run the project in release mode which is giving me issues saying **Warning:com.xtlib.models.Actor: can't find referenced class a**

I looked into the code of Actor which looks like

```
public static final Creator<Actor> CREATOR = new a();
```

Even though Proguard is not changing "CREATOR" name, it is changing the implementation. How can I skip proguard changing my declaration to a variable

Regards,
Sree

Comment: Any solutions ? Plz help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. The issue is with latest gradle plugin `1.5.0`. The latest gradle is placing the generated anonymous classes(ex : a.class) outside the package structure.

[image]

When I reverted my Gradle plugin to 1.2.3 for generating AAR, the generated classes are moved to their respective packages.

[image]

This solved my issue.

Cheers